# What does the Some(..) syntax mean?

Tags: rust, syntax

I wrote this snippet:

```rust
let my_option: Option<()> = None;
if my_option.is_some() {
    my_option.unwrap();
}
```

Clippy is telling me to use:

```rust
if let Some(..) = my_option {
    my_option.unwrap();
}
```

What does `Some(..)` mean? Is it just dropping the value similar to how using `_` would in some cases? And where can I find more information about when and where I can use the `..`?

Comment: `..` generally means "I don't care about what goes here" and you can use it lots of places, e.g. when unpacking a tuple: `let (a, .., b) = some_tuple;` will take the first and last element in the tuple and discard the rest. So yeah, it's kind of like `_` but can match multiple things at once whereas `_` only matches exactly one thing.

Comment: your code sample is strange anyway: `my_option.unwrap()` won't actually do anything because that expression has no side effects (since you've already guaranteed `my_option` is not `None`), it just returns the value "inside" the `Some` but doesn't actually do anything with that value. I guess this isn't actually your real code but without seeing that it's hard to say what the "best" way to write this is.

Comment: `Some(..) = my_option` is a pattern match that succeeds if and only if `my_option.is_some()` returns true. It's just a shorter, more idiomatic way of writing the same thing.

Comment: I would recommend to read this section: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html It gives kinda of wider perspective on this topic ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Clippy warning is slightly misleading. Let's first look at the full warning message:

```
warning: called `unwrap` on `my_option` after checking its variant with `is_some`
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
3 |     if my_option.is_some() {
  |     ---------------------- help: try: `if let Some(..) = my_option`
4 |         my_option.unwrap();
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(clippy::unnecessary_unwrap)]` on by default
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#unnecessary_unwrap
```

Clippy is complaining about the use of `unwrap()` after checking with `is_some()`. If you use `is_some()` only or `unwrap()` only, Clippy won't complain. It's only unwrapping after checking that's considered unidiomatic, since it can be easier done using `if let`.

I believe the reason for Clippy to suggest `if let Some(..) = my_option` is that the code does not track how the inner value is used later, so the suggestion needs to be somehow generic. In practice, you would hardly ever literally write `..` here, but instead write something like

```
if let Some(value) = my_option
```

to bind the inner value to a variable. Also note that `if let Some(..) = my_option` does not consume the option, while `if let Some(value) = my_option` does (if the inner type is not `Copy`).

In summary:

- If you want to check whether an option is `Some`, but are not interested in the contained value, you should use `if my_option.is_some()`.
- If you are certain at compile time that your option must be `Some`, and you want to extract the inner value, use `my_option.unwrap()` without any enclosing `if`.
- If you don't know whether the option is `Some`, and you want to extract the inner value only in case it is, use `if let Some(value) = my_value`.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the excellent answer by @SvenMarnach, `..` does have a meaning in patterns and it's indeed very similar to `_`: while `_` means "ignore one field here", `..` means "ignore zero or more fields here".

As such, in almost any place you can use `_` you can also use `..`, although it can lead to mistakes if fields are added later. The only exceptions are identifier patterns - you can do `if let _ = 123` but not `if let .. = 123`, and struct patterns because it has special syntax: ignoring one field is `Struct { field: _ }`, while ignoring many is `Struct { .. }`.